# jQuery - IF ELSE - Not reading any variables

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

### PROBLEM:

**UPDATE: I have found that its not just with returned data from a post.  Literally every `if` `else` statement disregards my variables** *almost* **entirely.**

I have tried to do something extremely simple to verify my statement above.

When the code below is executed, nothing happens.  I added `consol.log()` in before my if statement ( in place of the alert ) to make sure that its getting the data to the DOM and it is.

**HTML**

```
<input type='submit' name='Confirm' class='button' value='Confirm' >
<input type='submit' name='Cancel'  class='button' value='Cancel'  >
```

**JS**

```
$( '.button' ).on( 'click' , function() {

        var btnName = $( this ).attr( 'name' ) ;

        var cancel  = "Cancel"  ;
        var confirm = "Confirm" ;

        alert( btnName + cancel + confirm ) ;

        if ( btnName == cancel ) {

            //some function here . .

        } else if ( btnName == confirm ) {

            //some function here . .

        }
```

**EDIT If I run the code below, then the alert is always `Cancel`... What the fudge.**

```
$( '.button' ).on( 'click' , function() {

        var btnName  = $( '.button' ).attr( 'name' ) ;

        if ( btnName == "Cancel" )  {

            alert( 'Cancel' ) ;

        } else if ( btnName == "Confirm" ) {

            alert( 'Confirm' ) ;
        }
```

Not matter what i click, the functions in the `if` statement don't run.  The weird part is, when it hits `alert( btnName + cancel + confirm ) ;` The data that is alerted in the browser is accurate, as in, if I click `name='Confirm'` the alert output looks like `ConfirmCancelConfirm`...

Comment: What is 'returnedData' - seems like it could be undefined?

Comment: An if-else will give very different results from an if-elseif. If you're using if-elseif, could be that your returnedData (or btnName) undefined. Try a console.log(returnedData) before if statement to check the variable's value.

Comment: ( @ShaharZ )  I will give it a shot.  I don't know if it will prove much, I was verifying the value of the variable with `alert( btnName + Cancel + Confirm )` and the alert contains matching text.  i.e. if i click confirm then the alert dialog shows ( ConfirmCancelConfirm ) but the `if` statement wont run.

Comment: @ETHER34L did you try console.log in the `if` blocks to absolutely make sure? Sometimes if theres just a function there it could appear to do nothing even though it's running

Comment: @ShaharZ  I just added and ran `console.log( btnName ) ; console.log( cancel ) ; console.log( confirm )`.  When I click "cancel" then console: `Cancel` `Cancel` `Confirm`.  If I click "confirm" then console: `Confirm` `Cancel` `Confirm`

Comment: @ETHER43L is this in the `if` or `else if` block?

Comment: I think that you are somehow wrong about what is called and what isn't. I copypasted your example with buttons and it works. Put `alert(1)` and `alert(2)` in if-else branches and try again. Maybe copy your own code from here and paste it where it originally was.

Comment: Your second code block will only ever return the name of 1 button becuase you are doing `var btnName  = $( '.button' ).attr( 'name' ) ;` This is expected behaviour, and an error in your code. You should have `var btnName  = $(this).attr( 'name' ) ;`.

Comment: @Micheal Coxon    I caught that if you check out my solution.  Either way +1 thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have an error:

```
function( data ) {

        if ( returnedData == "Company Added" ) { //right here

            $( '#navAdmin' ).click() ;

        } else {

            alert( data ) ;

        }

    }
```

It should be

```
function( data ) {

        if ( data == "Company Added" ) {

            $( '#navAdmin' ).click() ;

        } else {

            alert( data ) ;

        }

    }
```

Comment: have you tried using data as is without transforming it in any way?

Comment: Yeah, initially I had it just throwing `data` right into the if statement.  It looked identical to your second javascript example.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your JS code.

```
if ( btnName != cancel ) {
// This function is normal
} else {
// This function is also work
}
```

That's work on my machine and browser. and your (if else else if code is also work).

> Chrome 44.0.2403.157 (64-bit)

Answer (score 0):

### Finally found my problem

I don't know where it's happening, but when I assign a variable, for example;

```
$( '.button' ).on( 'click' , function() {

    var btnName = $( this ).attr( 'name' ) ;
}
```

For some reason there was a bunch of whiteSpace being added before the string.

**Started Working With:**

```
$( '.button' ).on( 'click' , function() {

    var btnName     = $( this ).attr( 'name' ) ;
    var trimmedData = ( btnName ).trim() ;

    if ( trimmedData == "Confirm" ) {

        alert( "Confirm" ) ;

    } else if ( trimmedData == "Cancel" ) {

        alert( "Cancel"  ) ;

}
```

I put this into my `$.post` function and it is working as well.  I don't know where the extra space is coming from, any other thoughts are welcome.  Please Let me know if I am doing something horribly wrong here..